# Change SQL display result (Group by Name)

Tags: sql-server

My SQL query can show the following result:

```
Name   Project       Date
Peter    A           2014-12-11
Peter    C           2014-12-12
Peter    D           2014-12-13
John     B           2014-12-12
```

I want to display the result like the following. (Same names are not shown)

```
Name     Project           Date
Peter       A            2014-12-11
            C            2014-12-12
            D            2014-12-13
John        B            2014-12-12
```

My database server is MS SQL Server 2012 Standard . How to get the above result by SQL query?

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Use `window Function` to find the first Date in each group(name)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Name ELSE '' END Name,
       Project,
       Dates
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER (partition BY Name ORDER BY Dates) rn,*
        FROM   Tablename) a
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cedd7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below using `ROW_NUMBER()` function

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Name As OldName, Project, Date, 
          Row_Number() OVER (Partition By Name Order By Project) rn
   From YourTable
)
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN OldName ELSE '' End Name, Project, Date
FROM CTE
ORDER BY OldName, rn
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) = 1
             THEN Name
             ELSE ''
        END AS Name ,
        Project ,
        Date
FROM    t1
```